# SQL LEFT JOIN on 2 keys (join on X OR Y)

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM institutions
LEFT JOIN units ON Unit_Institution = Institution_Key
LEFT JOIN sites ON Site_Institution = Institution_Key OR Site_Key = Unit_Site
```

This request has extremely bad performance (despite indexes) because of the `OR`. Removing one side of it (no matter which one) divides the query cost by thousands.
What can I provide the MySQL engine to get solve this performance issue ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Write two separate queries and union them.

Comment: I doubt if distinct * helps performance. Can you be more specific than distincting all the columns from all the tables?

Comment: Indeed using `distinct` on a data set that can never contain duplicates is only introducing an unecessary and expensive sort.

Comment: In general, MySQL doesn't optimize `OR` conditions well. And `LEFT JOIN` is also generally slower than `INNER JOIN`, so don't use it if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT coalesce(sites_si.field, sites_sk.field) AS field -- ...
FROM institutions
LEFT JOIN units ON Unit_Institution = Institution_Key
LEFT JOIN sites_si ON Site_Institution = Institution_Key
LEFT JOIN sites_sk ON Site_Key = Unit_Site
```

You make two join and use coalesce to put them together.
Depending of you data it may be better.

Comment: Same as the first answer, but I didn't know about coalesce, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT <ALIAS>.<FIELD_NAME>,*
FROM INSTITUTIONS INS
LEFT JOIN UNITS UNI  ON UNI.UNIT_INSTITUTION    =   INS.INSTITUTION_KEY
LEFT JOIN SITES SIT1 ON SIT1.SITE_INSTITUTION   =   INS.INSTITUTION_KEY 
LEFT JOIN SITES SIT2 ON SIT2.SITE_KEY           =   (?).UNIT_SITE
```

try to join the same table two tame, the engine shouldn't need to check the "or" each time, but he will optimize joints with indexes
I've tried an example by my own and it's came out that the query with the "or" worked for 52 sec (for 10k records), instead, query with the two "join" took just 6 sec and same number of records

Comment: It is a tad annoying because you'll need to do IFNULLs on the alias for each field, but this does solving the performance problem (got the execution time divided by 1000). This is what I'll go with, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This `join` is not optimizable to a `HASH JOIN`, this is the reason it took too long to execute.

My suggestion is splitting the join condition into multiple queries, and then concatenate the results using `union` method.

i.e:

```
select distinct * 
from institutions
left join units ON Unit_Institution = Institution_Key
LEFT JOIN sites ON Site_Institution = Institution_Key

union

SELECT distinct *
from institutions 
left join units ON Unit_Institution = Institution_Key
LEFT JOIN sites Site_Key = Unit_Site
```

Comment: This will probably not work : you're on a `left join`, that mean you'll get your `institutions` twice (one with `null` and one with the data on the join). At least add an `AND` with exclusion of the other join `ON Site_Institution = Institution_Key AND Site_Key <> Unit_Site`